# What does the menu_masks variable do?

Tags: 7, routes, features

When I was building a feature (as in [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features)), I noticed the menu_masks variable. I have read [menu_get_ancestors()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_ancestors/7) and [_menu_router_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/_menu_router_save/7) but I still don't understand what it does.

On a more practical level: When I'm building a feature which defines the menu's for my site, should I export the menu_masks variable too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*menu_masks* is a Drupal variable used to find the possible ancestors of a menu item. It contains an array of values that are calculated from the paths defined from modules; each values is essentially a binary number where the digit is 1 when the path part doesn't contain a placeholder, and 0 when it contains a placeholder. For example, the number for node/%node/edit is 9 (101 in base 2), while the number for admin/structure/types/manage/%comment_node_type/comment/fields is 123 (1111011 in base 2).
The reason why numbers are used is avoid comparing strings; plus those numbers are easily sorted in a way that a number matching a path without placeholders is placed before a number matching a path with one or more placeholders. (The number for %/%/% would be 0, while the number for admin/appearance/list is 13.)

Notice that [`menu_get_ancestors()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_ancestors/7) doesn't return the ancestors of the path passed as argument, but the possible ancestors. Passing `array('node', '12', 'edit')` to the function, I would get the an array containing the following values, as result.

1. node/12/edit
2. node/12/%
3. node/%/edit
4. node/12
5. node/%
6. node

In my test site, only the third, the fifth, and the sixth are paths defined by the modules I installed.

You don't need to export the *menu_masks* variable: Its content is very specific for the site and it is re-calculated when [`menu_rebuild()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7) is called.
Drupal is still able to work correctly even in the case `menu_rebuild()` is not yet called, and that Drupal variable has not been set. You should not notice any performance issue, but if that would be the case, you can call `menu_rebuild()` or force Drupal to call that function; if you have the Devel module installed, you can easily force Drupal to rebuild its menus.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I'd give you another upvote if I could :-)